# How to attach a Visual Studio debugger to a Managed type process?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, windows-services

I've been following [this guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a50syb3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to debug a Windows Service application.

Basically, I need to attach the Visual Studio debugger to the process started after installing the Windows Service that has been developed. However, VS doesn't allow me attach the debugger to this process as shown in the following picture:

[image]

How can I attach the debugger to this process? If I clicked on any of the other processes the Attach button becomes enabled.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The Session column is relevant, services run in session 0.  You just haven't started the service yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check the checkbox `Show processes from all users`, then you will see `AutomatedReports.exe`. Attach that (not `AutomatedReports.vshost.exe`)

`vshost` is a host process to help with the debugging. More info on this [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185331.aspx)

Also you need to place the following line in your service code where you want to hit the break point.

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
```

Answer (score 2):

The service is probably running on a separate user account. Check the "Show processes from all users" checkbox and attach the debugger to `AutomatedReports.exe` process.

Also make sure that you are running a Debug build of the service, otherwise, you won't be able to debug a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to change the type of the code you are debugging?

Click on "Select ..."

Select "Debug these code types"

You can then select Types like: “Managed (v4.0…)"