# Attach visual studio debugger to user-defined started process programmatically

Tags: visual-studio, envdte

There are many posts of how to attach a debugger to a running Visual Studio process:

[Visual Studio: automatically attach debugger to process as soon as process starts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38969370/visual-studio-automatically-attach-debugger-to-process-as-soon-as-process-start)

[Starting a process using Visual Studios' DTE with debugger attached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73750881/starting-a-process-using-visual-studios-dte-with-debugger-attached)

[How to attach a Visual Studio debugger to a Managed type process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10649351/how-to-attach-a-visual-studio-debugger-to-a-managed-type-process)

all of these suggestions work, but they are rather slow. One of the biggest problems is that when you start a process manually, you get the process id. VS however has its own notion of a `Process` structure where I have to search through the list of VS `Processes` to find the matching `Process` and the `Process ID`.

My question, to get rid of this problem, **if there is a way to start the process directly using the `DTE`** where I hope the debugger is automatically attached? I found there is an `IVsDebugLaunch` which I can get from the VS ServiceProvider but only when running as a VS extension. But I found no way to get it when using the DTE.